# how to design good logic in the authorization mechanism

Tags: reactjs

I learn to react and have problems understandinghow to implement good logic for authorization mechanisms.

My backend working on Node API.Bellow description of my authorization:#1 Registration- User registration, and send to backend login, and password in bcrypt.

#2 Login

- User logged and get a token from JWT

#3 When the User is Admin- The frontend asks the backend, about permission, if the user has permission can get access to the section in the website for admins, by protected routes, in react-router-v6.

My questions:- I want for each page view, checking that user has permission for protected routes, it is good?

Code responsible for it:

```
// function that checking if user has permission to access the page
const checkPermission = (permissions) => {
  console.log(permissions);
  const configuration = {
    method: "get",
    url: "http://localhost:3005/auth-endpoint",
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${permissions}`,
    },
  };

  // make the API call
  axios(configuration)
    .then(() => {})
    .catch((error) => {
      error = new Error();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way for checking the authentication is to separate private and public routes and use conditional rendering. that way private pages can’t be accessed and your app is always predicable
for demonstrations :

```
<>
    token ? <PrivateRoutes /> : null
    <PublicRoutes />
</>
```